# Selenium and ChromeDriver Issues

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

When the ChromeDriver version does not match my current chrome version, i upgrade chromedriver by the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Then i use selenium for scraping the website data, but still i got some errors. Anyone can help me with this issue? Appreciate.

```
import time

import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.binance.com/cn/futures/funding-history/0")
time.sleep(5)
```

The errors took place when the above code is ran which has been attached.[image]

Comment: As stated, your version of chromedriver does not match the version of Google Chrome installed on your machine. You have chromedriver v88 but Google Chrome v90. You need to download the newer chromedriver v90

Comment: i have downloaded and installed through this linkhttps://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=90.0.4430.24/ .  But the problem still remained. Not sure why

Comment: You need to delete your older version of chromedriver and make sure the 90... version is in the standard location for your OS

Answer (score 0):

You may try to include the below code to get the latest version automatically

**through PIP :**

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

**Usage**

Just type `import chromedriver_autoinstaller` in the module you want to use chromedriver.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

Read more about auto upgrade [here](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/)